# How does AWS FIFO SQS deduplication ID work?

Tags: amazon-web-services, duplicates, amazon-sqs

I'm trying to use the AWS SQS FIFO service together with an Elastic Beanstalk worker environment.

Let's say I send a message with `MessageDeduplicationId` `test`, if I continue sending this exact message in the next 5 minutes, the message will be ignored, correct?

What happens if I send a message with `MessageDeduplicationId` `test` , the consumer processes the message and deletes it, then, in about 1 minute, I send the exact same message again. Will this message be ignored?

My question is, does deduplication occur as long as the same `MessageDeduplicationId` **is still in queue/flight?** Or is the id banner forever, no other message with the same id can be sent.

Thanks.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

*What happens if I send message with MessageDeduplicationId test , the consumer processes the message and the deletes it, then, in about 1 minute, I send the exact same message again. Will this message be ignored?*

Answer seems to be: **Yes**

> Amazon SQS continues to keep track of the message deduplication ID even after the message is received and deleted.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/using-messagededuplicationid-property.html

Comment: I can confirm this. In a 5 minute interval, it will ignore the message stack completely. (First paragraph of the shared link)

Answer (score 10):

> I continue sending this exact messages in the next 5 minutes, the message will be ignored, correct?

Correct.  Any longer than 5 minutes, though, and it will be accepted again and delivered again and then ignored for another 5 minutes.

Comment: Ok, but what if the message is processed and deleted from the queue in, lets say 5 seconds after it was sent. What happens if I send the same deduplication id in the next 4 minutes and 55 seconds?

Comment: The message would be accepted by SQS and then discarded because the purpose of the deduplication ID is to help ensure "exactly once" delivery -- to allow you to safely resubmit a message to the queue if you are unsure whether you submitted it without error, before.  Example: you submit a message to the queue and while the `200 OK` response is on the wire on its way back to you, you lose your Internet link.  The queue has the message, but you have no way to confirm that, as a producer.  So, you submit it again, knowing it will only be delivered once.